# Angular 2 route parameters limitation

Tags: angularjs, angular, routes

AngularJs(1*) considered following route is a valid one and works without any issues.

```
/samples/id-:id
```

But in Angular2, the same route is not valid and giving following exception

```
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'samples/id-0'
```

is there are any way to overcome this issue?

**Note: `/samples/:id` is valid route in Angular2. issue is there if we combine route parameter and static text in one segment**

Comment: Why not just remove the `id-` part when you read the param. Seems to be easy enough.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, it won't let me to go up to that level. when i define the route and run, it will give the above error message.

Comment: I mean using a route path like `/samples/:id` instead of `/samples/id-:id` and then add/remove the `id-` part when you pass or read params. AFAIK having a part of a "directory" being a parameter is just not supported in the current router.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, yes it will work for this scenario. but in case of multiple params, it will be hard to extract this. ex:  `x-0-y-1` where x,y parameter names. and combination of x,y will provide an unique identifier for the resource.